# Running only selected tests with dynamic input

Tags: karate

I have tried few approaches to solve my problem but with no success (I do need to improve my Java :)), so I am hopping that I am missing something or that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have multiple microservices that I need to test. I should be able to test all at once or only the ones I want. Each service has its own DB and different feature files. Note that these services may not be all up and running.

I can run tests with manually setting config for each service. Ideally I would like to pass a variable with service name in command line and the tests should start.

In current set up I use callSingle to run DBInit.feature which runs SQL scripts to populate my DB. I have also set global variables that are used in feature files. And this works fine.

Problems start when I add more feature files that are used to test the service that is not running. And when I have to use callSingle for specified service to populate its DB.

The first idea was to use different envs, but I could need 5 envs to be executed in a single run and with one report. Then I was thinking to implement runner for each service but I am not sure if these runners run in parallel and not sure how could I populate DB in this case?

Is it possible to use custom variable that will be passed to main test class.

```
public class DemoTestSelected {
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        TestBase.beforeClass();
    }     

    @Test
    public void testSelected() {
        List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("~@ignore");
        List<String> features = Arrays.asList("classpath:demo/cats");
        String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
        Results results = Runner.path(features)
                .tags(tags)
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .reportDir(karateOutputPath).parallel(5);
        DemoTestParallel.generateReport(karateOutputPath);
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

}
```

For example tags and features to be set in config?

Answer (score -1):

I re-read your question a few times and gave up trying to understand it. But I'll lay down a couple of principles:

- you should use tags to decide which features to run / not-run. try to fit everything you need to this model and don't complicate things
- for more control, you can set some "system property" on the command-line and maybe before you use the `Runner`, you can write some Java logic which would be - "if `karate.env` (or some other system property) is `foo`, then select tags `one`. `two` and `three` etc.
- yes the Karate 1.0 series can technically run multiple `Runner` instances in parallel, but that is left to you and we don't have an example, it would require you to manage threads or a Java [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) manually

Comment: Thank You for answer.
I did try using tags, but tags dont work with `karate.callSingle`. I need callSingle to populate DB. I will try to implement something with Java.

Comment: `tags dont work with karate.callSingle` - that doesn't make any sense to me either. anyway, all the best

Comment: Using `karate.callSingle(feature1.feature)` in `karate-config.js` where `feature1` has two scenarios with different tags `(@tag1 and @tag2)`, both scenarios are executed each time even if I use `-Dkarate.options="--tags @tag1"`.

ps. thx for the link

Comment: @senaid that is the expected behavior. once you use any kind of `call` tags are not involved unless you use the "call by tag" option: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector

Comment: I didnt pay attention to that. Thank You very much

Comment: One can run multiple `Runner` instances in parallel by 1) Adding runner's in separate `@Test` methods 2) Use the JUnit annotation(Class Level) `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)` 3) pass the JVM argument `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true`